# Render a Table inside select option the HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to render a table inside the select option in HTML and Bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Its not possible to put any `element` inside `select - option`. So I would suggest you to make it work using `tab-indent` inside options to create such view.. BTW are you using any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can style a dropdown-menu with some columned children.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-4">
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-1 item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-1 item 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-1 item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-4">
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-2 item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-2 item 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-2 item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-4">
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-3 item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-3 item 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">Column-3 item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is a [Bootyply](http://www.bootply.com/iO3qW3YQjr).

**EDIT**

This is more of a solution to your question: [Bootyply](http://www.bootply.com/OqaTD3VUh1)